# Windows multi-thread makes memory usage increasing

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, memory

I am using `SSE` instructions and `Windows multi-thread` to implement matrix multiplication. When the matrix's dimension is large, such as 1024 by 1024, it will take a long time to get the result.

And when it runs at 4096*4096, the `exe` takes little memory, say 192M, but, the memory usage of my machine is increasing from 20% to 97%, I think there maybe something wrong with the `Windows multi-thread`.

The following are my codes.

`main.cpp`

```
#include "sse_matrix.h"
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<float> * left = new vector<float>(size, 0);
    vector<float> * right = new vector<float>(size, 0);
    vector<float> * result = new vector<float>(size, 0);
    // initialize value
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j ++)
        {
            (*left)[i*dim + j] = j;
            (*right)[i*dim + j] = j;
        }

    }
    cout << "1. INFO: value initialized, starting matrix multiplication" << endl;
    // calculate the result
    clock_t my_time = clock();
    SSE_Matrix_Multiply(left, right, result, 4);
    cout << "2. INFO: SSE matrix multiplication result has got" << endl;
    cout << "3. INFO: time(ms): " << float(clock() - my_time) << endl;

    delete left;
    delete right;
    delete result;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

`sse_matrix.h`

```
#ifndef __SSE_MATRIX_H__
#define __SSE_MATRIX_H__

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

const int dim = 4096;
const int size = dim * dim;

struct Matrix_Info 
{
    vector<float> * A;
    int ax, ay;
    vector<float> * B;
    int bx, by;
    vector<float> * C;
    int cx, cy;
    int m;
    int n;
};

void Transpose_Matrix_SSE(float * matrix)
{
    __m128 row1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&matrix[0*4]);
    __m128 row2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&matrix[1*4]);
    __m128 row3 = _mm_loadu_ps(&matrix[2*4]);
    __m128 row4 = _mm_loadu_ps(&matrix[3*4]);
    _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(row1, row2, row3, row4);
    _mm_storeu_ps(&matrix[0*4], row1);
    _mm_storeu_ps(&matrix[1*4], row2);
    _mm_storeu_ps(&matrix[2*4], row3);
    _mm_storeu_ps(&matrix[3*4], row4);

}

float * Shuffle_Matrix_Multiply(float * left, float * right)
{
    __m128 _t1, _t2, _sum;
    _sum = _mm_setzero_ps(); // set all value of _sum to zero
    float * _result = new float[16];
    float _res[4] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
        {
            _t1 = _mm_loadu_ps(left + i * 4);
            _t2 = _mm_loadu_ps(right + j * 4);
            _sum = _mm_mul_ps(_t1, _t2);
            _mm_storeu_ps(_res, _sum);
            _result[i * 4 + j] = _res[0] + _res[1] + _res[2] + _res[3];
        }
    }
    return _result;
}

float * SSE_4_Matrix(struct Matrix_Info * my_info)
{
    int m = my_info->m;
    int n = my_info->n;
    int ax = my_info->ax;
    int ay = my_info->ay;
    int bx = my_info->bx;
    int by = my_info->by;
    //1. split Matrix A and Matrix B
    float * _a = new float[16];
    float * _b = new float[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
        {
            _a[i*m + j] = (*my_info->A)[(i + ax) * n + j + ay];
            _b[i*m + j] = (*my_info->B)[(i + bx) * n + j + by];
        }
    }
    //2. transpose Matrix B
    Transpose_Matrix_SSE(_b);
    //3. calculate result and return a float pointer
    float * result =  Shuffle_Matrix_Multiply(_a, _b);
    free(_a);
    free(_b);
    return result;
}

DWORD WINAPI Matrix_Multiply(LPVOID my_info)
{
    int m = ((struct Matrix_Info *)my_info)->m;
    int n = ((struct Matrix_Info *)my_info)->n;
    int cx = ((struct Matrix_Info *)my_info)->cx;
    int cy = ((struct Matrix_Info *)my_info)->cy;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
        {
            float * temp = SSE_4_Matrix(((struct Matrix_Info *)my_info));
            (*((struct Matrix_Info *)my_info)->C)[(i + cx) * n + j + cy] += temp[i*m + j];
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void SSE_Matrix_Multiply(vector<float> * left, vector<float> * right, vector<float> * result, int thread_num)
{
    struct Matrix_Info * my_info = new struct  Matrix_Info[thread_num];
    HANDLE * handle = new HANDLE[thread_num];
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_num; i ++)
    {
        my_info[i].A = left;
        my_info[i].B = right;
        my_info[i].C = result;
        my_info[i].n = dim;
        my_info[i].m = 4;
    }
    int id = 0;
    // Matrix A row:i, column:j
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i += 4)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j += 4)
        {
            // Matrix B row:j column:k
            for (int k = 0; k < dim; k += 4)
            {
                my_info[id].ax = i;
                my_info[id].ay = j;
                my_info[id].bx = j;
                my_info[id].by = k;
                my_info[id].cx = i;
                my_info[id].cy = k;
                if (id < thread_num)
                {
                     handle[id] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Matrix_Multiply, (LPVOID)(&my_info[id]), 0, 0 );
                     id ++;
                }
                if (id == thread_num)
                {
                    for (int _i = 0; _i < id; _i ++)
                        WaitForMultipleObjects(thread_num, &handle[_i], TRUE, INFINITE);
                    id = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(my_info);
    free(handle);
}

#endif
```

So, when `dim` is 4096, and when `exe` runs, it takes about 192M of the memory, but the memory usage increases from 20% to 97% before I got the result.

My OS is `Windows 10` and IDE is `Visual Studio 2012`, my memory is 8G.

Comment: Creating threads takes memory.. yes.. That is expected and by design.. perhaps can even be called necessary to a large extent.. Haven't looked at the code very closely, but you do seem to be creating a lot of threads.. Do you really need to? FYI, creating more threads, than the number of cores on the machines will not help your throughput much.. and can actually hurt performance as well as memory (as you see). So keep the number of threads to a reasonable number (2-3x number of cores).

Comment: You're doing a lot of mallocs and frees in your threads.  This may contribute to the memory overhead (if the memory system is too busy to clean up freed blocks), but will definitely kill the threaded performance because malloc is not multithreaded (so 3 threads will wait for the 1 that is in it).  Just store those 16 float arrays in Matrix_Info struct and don't allocate anything in your thread code.  (Also there is a lot of overhead with all those CreateThread calls.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I must free some memory, if not, it may lead to memory leaks.

Comment: The use of dynamic allocations for small, fixed-size arrays (like `float[16]`) is probably killing your performance. E.g. the result of `Shuffle_Matrix_Multiply()` is just returned from `SSE_4_Matrix()` to `Matrix_Multiply()` where it is used once and then released. Use an array on the stack who's address you pass to the according functions as parameter instead. BTW: You know about `std::vector<>`, but why don't you use it consistently but instead perform manual memory management everywhere?

Comment: @AlexanderYau `new vector<…>` is unnecessary. Just declare them as locals: `std::vector<float> left(size); …`.

Comment: Using `new` and `free()` smells to me. What is wrong with `delete[]`?

Comment: No, don't use `delete[]`. Simply declare the variables to live on the stack: `float _a[16];`

Comment: Your worst problem by far is the number of threads you create. Each thread does far too little work to justify the overhead of spawning it. You should create just four threads and subdivide the work so that threads share as few written pages as possible. E.g., allocate result rows 0–1023 to thread 0, rows 1024–2047 to thread 1, etc.

Comment: There are countless errors in your code. Your belief that your code is fine but that the defect lies in Windows is your real problem. How will you find your own errors if you won't look at your own code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, If there are countless errors in my code, please point out. I know there are some errors, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: The comments above point many of them out. Pairing new with free. Spurious use of new, caused by using variables that are pointers rather than simple values. Excessive numbers of threads created. And I'm sure there are more errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thank you sir, I need to rewrite my code, thank your for your advice.

Comment: Choosing SSE and then going straight for **unaligned** memory access pretty much tops all the other wrongs in the code. You should consider writing a single-threaded version of your code, using plain floating point operators. Then profile the code. If you find that it is your bottleneck, try optimizing it. Optimizing at that level requires that you are intimately familiar with both the OS and the target architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating threads with `dwStackSize = 0` of `CreateThread` which leads to a [default stack size of 1MB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The memory required by the threads is **not** shown correctly by the task manager which you can test with the following little test application:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

DWORD WINAPI thread(LPVOID pData)
{
   HANDLE hThread;

   hThread = GetCurrentThread();
   while (SuspendThread(hThread) == -1);

   return (0);
}

int main()
{
   int cnt;
   HANDLE hThread;
   DWORD tid;

   cnt = 0;
   do
   {
      hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 4096, thread, NULL, 0, &tid);
      if (hThread != NULL)
      {
         cnt++;
      }

      SleepEx(10, FALSE);
   }
   while (hThread != NULL);

   printf("%d threads; error: %d\n", cnt, GetLastError());

   printf("\n\nend.");
   getch();

   return (0);
}
```

I'm able to create 1597 threads on my machine so the memory usage of my application should be somewhere around 1.5GB but task manager shows just around 45MB.

My guess is that the behaviour you're observing is caused by the display of task manager... this may be worth investigating a little bit more...

Another thing concerning your implementation:

- You're waiting for all threads to end before creating new threads. You may want to check set `bWaitAll = FALSE` and evaluate the return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects` the create a new thread right away instead of waiting for all threads to finish processing...
- As mentioned before your shouldn't allocate small amounts of memory like `float[16]`. Think of a way to avoid this...

Comment: The task Manager correctly shows the **memory used** by the thread. You're limited to 1597 threads because you're compiling for 32 bits and running out of **address space**. A default thread takes up about 8 kB of memory and exactly 1 MB of address space. (The exact memory usage depends on the runtime libraries and thread-local variables)

Comment: This answer is incorrect and incomplete, simply missing the litany of errors in the code in the question.

Comment: `You're waiting for all threads to end before creating new threads. You may want to check set bWaitAll = FALSE and evaluate the return value of WaitForMultipleObjects the create a new thread right away instead of waiting for all threads to finish processing.` I think you it is a good advice for me.